# HQL: m to n to m join with full match

Tags: hibernate, join, many-to-many, hql

so i have the following model:

```
Lecturer <----m:n ----> Topic <----m:n -----> Coursetype
```

The attributes are:

Lecturer.qualifications

Topic.qualifiedLecturers

Topic.coursetypes

Coursetype.topics

i now want to find a lecturer who is qualified for all topics in a certain courseType.
My approach so far is this:

```
select l
from Lecturer l join l.qualifications t join t.courseTypes ct
where ct = :ct //or ct.id = :id for performance
```

Unfortunately, the join will also result in lecturers who are only qualified for SOME topics in a courseType, not all of them. I tried several things with HQL collections in the query but no luck so far. So i need a way to express that l.qualifications must be a subset of ct.topics